# Using hibernate with multithreaded socket server

Tags: multithreading, hibernate, sockets

I have one question.

Is it my correct understanding if I'm using multithreaded socket server in java would I create the sessionfactory in the server and then pass a new session to each thread created in the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Hibernate session is not thread-safe, and must not be shared between threads. It's thus the created thread that should create its own session.

But a session shouldn't be open for the duration of a thread, either. A session's lifespan is typically the same as a transaction lifespan: very short.